# Autotune / Python / Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, audio

I want to develop a "I'm T-Pain app" for mobile devices. The input is my voice, and the output is my voice auto-tuned.

I've found an example on Github of what i'm looking for [PyAutoTune](https://github.com/ederwander/PyAutoTune).

Unfortunately it is developed in Python, but I also found Skulpt, which enables me to write Python in Javascript. Do you think it's possible to produce the Autotune effect this way?

I'm using Icenium, I have to develop my application with HTML/CSS/Javascript.

So I wonder if Skulpt will allow me to do this project with Javascript or is it a too limited tool?

Comment: Nice one! Good luck, sounds cool like Cher and Kanye West :) I see it is a long time ago, hope you nailed it.

Comment: Technical demo in my opinion proving concept to be possible (although laggy at the moment): https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/Vocoder/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The library is written in C; it is an extension to Python. If your platform does not allow C programs, I'm afraid you are out of luck.

If you are able to compile C code or somehow translate it to Javascript, you could avoid the Python bindings (PyAutoTuner.c) altogether and work with the original library from http://tombaran.info/autotalent.html

Comment: the only solution would be to compile the C program using emscripten, the python using skulpt, and emulate the emscripten/skulpt interaction ;-D

Comment: err, I was being sarcastic, though it should theoretically possible, I don't think you should waste time on something *that* complicated. I'm pretty sure, if you use the `PyAutoTune` C files as an example so you can write something in JS you could achieve a better result. Or maybe you can just rewrite the `PyAutoTune` C files to get rid of the python dependencies, compile the core symbols, and access to them using JS once compiled using emscripten. But AFAICT, there's still much improvements to be done with firefox' sound handling.

Comment: @zmo So you're suggesting me to rewrite the PyAutotune.c in javascript (so rewrite also autotalent.c , autotalent.h ,  mayer-fft.c ?) . Once done I suppose to use Skulpt to run FromFileAutoTune.py. Am I right ? (sorry i'm a beginner :s)

Comment: PyAutoTune: Sounds like both patent- and trade-mark infrigment'r's! ;)

Comment: @Marko that makes me like their project ;-)

Comment: I'd say that maths in an Electronics or physics degree (or a maths degree) is probably the pre-req for understanding how this kind of algorithm actually works, or improving on it.  However, there's no requirement here for the resulting audio so sound in any way realistic, so that eases things somewhat!

Comment: There is, incidentally another example of how to do it (with some background explanation) from [DSPDimension](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/), which  might prove useful.   They estimate original frequency using SFFT and differentiation.   The hard bit about this is in fact pitch detection (which is not necessarily the same as the predominant frequency in the signal).

Comment: Also, PyAutoTune doesn't work. Make no attempt to use it. I tried to use FromFileAutoTune.py and it gives me a segmentation fault. If I were you I would try to find a different program that does the same thing, which is what I am trying to do right now. In case you do know what the segmentation fault is due to, could you tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the python stuff is just exposing and using C symbols. So Skulpt is no help in what you want to achieve.

Then, you've got really few options, that leads to lot of work:

- rewrite the whole `PyAutoTune` C libraries in Javascript from scratch. It'll be helpful to figure out complicated algorithms, but that's **a lot** of work ;
- fork the `PyAutoTune` C libraries, so you remove everything that is python related. Then either

  - you compile these libraries with emscripten to embed them in your firefox browser, and though I don't know how to do it, get symbols from the emscripten compiled stuff so you can call the C function from a Javascript you'll have to write (somehow equivwalent to `FromFileAutoTune.py`) or
  - you use the native C code execution extension from chrome (I don't remember its name), export all symbols so you can use them from a javascript code you've written.

I never done that kind of stuff, I just know that is possible... But both features are under heavy development by chrome and mozilla developers, and may lack good documentation, especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: I bet that FFT implementation won't be pretty (or particularly fast) in Javascript - even when JITed.  There's a good reason modern browsers provide implementations as a built-in.

Comment: @Marko :/ then what i'm suppose to do ? it seems very very difficult unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I'll tell you that this is a **REALLY** big challenge for a beginner to really cover features of C, JS and browsers. But, indeed, the end result won't be a lot efficient, though stuff like [PNaCl](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/building-and-testing-portable-native-client) for chrome or [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten‎)for Firefox are trying to leverage those problematics.

Comment: @zmo ok so it isn't for me. I find this : https://github.com/onkis/autotune.js . it's apply effect on .wav file but not really Autotune effect. I'll try to modify it .

Comment: that's indeed a good choice, you can try to make it work on a stream!